# @include inside @foreach loop is not working in Laravel blade template

Tags: foreach, laravel-5, include

I have these lines of code in my view blade of laravel 5.2, Problem is that foreach is including only for one row , means only one module has been including not for all .

```
  @foreach($modules as $module) 
        @include('modules.'.$module->module_name)
  @endforeach
```

But when i am executing below code i am getting all modules

```
    @foreach($modules as $module) 
       {{$module->module_name}}
    @endforeach
```

Please help me where i am wrong .  Thanks !!!!

Comment: Blade will generate php codes. So, open your view source code and see if the PHP  and path is correct.

Comment: Thanks Drudge , my paths were wrong . It is working now !!!

Comment: great it worked for u .